Scala enum not working with rdd map function in Spark
When I try to use enum in custom mapping function in Scala it throws the following error
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MODULE$
 at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1703)
 at scala.Enumeration.readResolve(Enumeration.scala:61)

When I use string instead of enum values it works perfectly fine, but when I do what I did below it throws error. Enum is working perfectly when I try to print the values but throws error in this case.
def parseRow(row: Row): String = {
 val id = row.getAs[String](ID)
 id match {
   case ENUM.val1.toString =>
     do something
   case ENUM.val2.toString =>
     do something 
}

df.rdd.map(parseRow).toDF("new_id")

I even tried using withName to extract enum value of id and then in case statement match it with enum values, but that gives same error. 
I even tried using df instead of rdd, but that again throws same error.

scala.Enumeration is extremely broken and nobody uses it. Just use a simple ADT using sealed traits + case objects if you are in Scala 2 or enum if you are in Scala 3.
